# plupload - how to trigger "stuff" after files uploaded

Tags: javascript, plupload

I did ask this on the plupload forum but didn't get a usable response.

What I would like to do is redirect to an acknowledgement page after plupload has performed its magic, ideally I would like to capture the recently uploaded filename and print that on the new page so that a user will have a link to the file that they had uploaded.

In the plupload documentation there is a "DONE" property which I suspect will be what I need, however not being a javascript writer, I don't really know how to utilise it!

So, if possible, could someone answer with an indication of the code I will need and where it should go?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After lots of research and some help from a friend I managed to follow the technique used on this page http://www.plupload.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?id=92